# RewriteCond and RewriteRule, how to combine two rewrite rules to one

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rules to meet this objective:

1. The query string brandPage=1 (example a,b,c,d), needs to be removed but any addition query strings are to be retained (example B)
2. /browse needs to be changed to /brand

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)brandPage=1&?(.*)$`
`RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1%2`
`RewriteRule /browse/(.*) /brand/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]`

Examples
`a. /browse/aerolatte/_/N-1z13u3z?brandPage=1
 b. /browse/room/aerolatte/_/N-4wk7Z1z13u3z?brandPage=1&icmp=abc 
 c. /browse/women/womens-tops-600001558/armani-jeans/_/N-53f3Z4gpgZ1z13u2h?brandPage=1
 d. /browse/%C3%A5ry-trays/_/N-1z13va1?brandPage=1`

e. This should NOT be matched `/browse/aerolatte/_/N-1z13u3zq`

What a redirected url would look like:

`/brand/aerolatte/_/N-1z13u3z

 /brand/room/aerolatte/_/N-4wk7Z1z13u3z?icmp=abc

 /brand/women/womens-tops-600001558/armani-jeans/_/N-53f3Z4gpgZ1z13u2h`

This works for examples a to d, but it also matched for e.  I now understand this is because only the first RewriteRule after the RewriteCond is linked, therefore how I can combine the two RewriteRule or can I simple chain them altogether using [C] on each line?

I'm using IHS 6.1.0.47 (Apache 2.0.47)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never done this but if I understand you right, you could try setting an environment variable when the first rewrite is done, then adding a condition check for this variable before the second rewrite. Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)brandPage=1&?(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1%2 [E=done:1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:done} =1
RewriteRule /browse/(.*) /brand/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```